# Limited Dissolve and face loop selection

Tags: modifiers, faces

I'm trying to use `Limited Dissolve` on a larger model, which brings the model down from `600k vertices` to `100k vertices` (no this is not hand generated :)). Below, you can see a much more simplified model just for this problem.

I created a plane that was sub-divided into several faces. I then extruded the edge faces to create a wall as seen here:

[image]

I selected the edge faces by going into `Edit mode`, then `alt + RMB` and clicked two of the faces around the border to give me the selection seen above.

In this model (same problem I have in my bigger, more complex model), I have several extra vertices and subsequently faces, that aren't needed. For example: Since the exterior wall is a straight line, that could just be a single quad.

Alas, I came across `Limited Dissolve`, which I think is exactly what I need to be using. So, in `Edit mode` I pressed `A` twice to select everything, pressed `X` and clicked `Limited Dissolve`. That produced this:

[image]

I unfortunately now can't seem to use the `ALT + RMB` to select that same outer loop as seen in the first image. I need to be able to select the edge faces as seen above to apply texturing across large segments with lots of faces, but the `Limit Dissolve` seems to break that ability.

Furthermore, why do the face centers (the dots) seem to no longer be centered in the quads?

I found some similar posts regarding edges but not with regards to the face loop selection:

[Loop cut entirely after dissolving an edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/loop-cut-entirely-after-dissolving-an-edge)
[Why isn't 'Loop selection' working if object only has edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43738/why-isnt-loop-selection-working-if-object-only-has-edges)

Thanks!

Comment: The selected face is no longer a quad, it is an N-gon with 6 edges because of the small face on the top of the model.

Comment: @Denis Hmm. Is there a way to get `Limited Dissolve` I suppose to only reduce to quads not N-gon (if you can imagine how I'm just trying to reduce the vertices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the top faces and delete them. Click *Select* -> *Select All by Trait* -> *Loose geometry* to select the edges on top that are no longer connected to faces.

[image]

Press <kbd>delete</kbd> -> *Only Edges & Faces* to remove the unnecessary edges.

[image]

Select all geometry by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and press <kbd>delete</kbd> -> *Limited Dissolve*.

[image]

Select the top edges, and click *Mesh* -> *Edges* -> *Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

You now have this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so @Denis definitely put me down the correct path. So, when using `Limited Dissolve`, it does create N-Polygons.

So, eventually I managed to stumble across https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?254109-convert-n-gon-to-quads-tris . I'd highly recommend adding the plugin to blender, which when activated, under the 'Object Data' tab, it will count the number of Ngons, Quads, and Tris for you.

Anyways, so when I clicked 'Select ngons' they popped right up nice and highlighted. I then converted the ngons to triangles, then back to quads, and that seemed to clean things up.

Just wanted to update this post, should anyone come across this.